# For the expression "bumf**k, Egypt", is "bumf**k" an adjective and "Egypt" a noun?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, offensive-language

I'm asking about the structure of the expression. If the answer is YES, then what's the reason for the comma. Besides, which Egypt is meant, "The Arab Republic of Egypt" or that "region of Illinois", near Chicago?
— Edited: I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: -1 After your question about ["F**k you"](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/498959/2), you don't know that offensive words in titles should be sanitized/bowdlerized?

Comment: Sometimes wikitionary  is useful: (vulgar, idiomatic, US, originally military slang) The middle of nowhere. So,obviously, even google didn't work for you.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Sorry for that. I edited my question, and I'm not asking about the meaning. What I mean is: if it is an adjective and a noun, then why use a comma?

Comment: @Lambie Of course Google works, and of course I googled it and saw that entry in Wikitionary before I asked here, but my question is: if it is an adjective and a noun, then why use a comma?

Comment: Because it's a noun: it's like saying: nowheresville, USA.

Comment: The comma seems to be separating "city, state" as in "New York, NY" or "Houston, TX", so the adjacent is meant as a noun, which wiktionary would have told you. Although, it's liable to be understood as adverb or adjective in spoken speech, similar to "I know fuck all". What's the difference to you? It's an explitive to be parsed however one feels like, pretty close to explitives. What's the syntax of "Shit!"? Your mother ...

Comment: @vectory ...What do you mean by what you said last — i.e. What's the syntax of "Shit!"? Your mother ... ??! Ha?

Comment: What you mean by "what do you mean?"!

Comment: @vectory I mean what do want to say? What about—"Your mother..." — that you said last?

Comment: @vectory If what you mean by "Your mother..." is what I understood, then: Your mother!

Comment: See, you misunderstand. The last bit was a minor point of my comment. If you don't acknowledge the overarching points, there's no reason to go into detail. The slur does not alter the meaning, it is just an addage, to make a point. The point here was to show that slurs have an effect whether they are meaningful in the context or not. Point in case, your retort draws heavily on context. The aaddage only explains your attitude (I do not even know what that word really means, thanks Dr. Dre).

Comment: @vectory  Why not speak in a simpler way? I'm not a native speaker like you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another example of how important the context is to the use of a word or phrase.
The two words are used to indicate not just a far away place but a very far away place. This is most likely to have been used first in the USA so if you live in Africa or the Mediterranean it would not have the same force for you.

The words are used like Town-Name, US-State-Name. This is why the comma, just as in Chicago, Illinois or Baltimore, Maryland. The imaginary town name of b-f is itself an expletive of the most derogatory type. The country of Egypt is generally taken to mean a very remote location and reflects no opinion of Egypt other than ignorance. It has been a frequently used, very crude term to dismiss the origin or current location of a the noun.